# $min(u,const)$ is a function in $W^{1,2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

**Statement**

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ (denoting a Sobolev Space) and $c>0$.

I want to prove that $min(u,c) \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. ($c$ denotes a constant function, i.e. $c1_{\Omega}$)

**My approaches:**

First approach:

I know that for $u \in C^1(\Omega)$ and $\partial_i u = 0$ on $\{u=c\}$ it holds:

$\partial_i min(u,c) = 
\begin{cases}
    \partial_i u, & \text{for } u < c \\
    0, & \text{for } u > c \\
    0, & \text{for } u = c.
\end{cases}$

So I assume that the weak derivative looks similar. However I'm having trouble to show that the weak derivative of $min(u,c)$ is of the form above. If I do it by the definition I get for $i \in \{1,...,n\}$:

$$\int_{\Omega}min(u(x),c)\partial_i\phi(x) \, dx = \int_{u<c}u(x)\partial_i\phi(x) \, dx + c\int_{u \geq c}\partial_i \phi(x) \, dx$$
However I dont see how this yields any results, since (to my knowledge) neither $1_{u<c}u$ nor $c1_{u \geq c}$ doesn't need to have a weak derivative. (Reason: for $n=1$ and $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ I know, that $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ needs to be continuous and the $1_{u \geq c}$ clearly isn't.) Another problem would be to prove that $\partial_i u = 0$ on $\{u=c\}$, which I was not able to do yet.

Second approach:

I know that I can rewrite $min(u,c)=\frac{u+c-|u-c|}{2}$. Further I know that for $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$: $|u| \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. Problem is that I don't think that $u-c \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ in general. So I tried an approximation argument using some kind of chain rule (Stampacchias Theorem, like in [If $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, prove that $Du=0$ a.e. on the set $\{u=0\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108621/if-u-in-w1-pu-prove-that-du-0-a-e-on-the-set-u-0)) but that didn't yield any result yet...

Could somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: No, $\Omega$ doesn't need to be bounded. Do you think the assertion is false, if $\Omega$ is not bounded?

Comment: No, but if it were bounded, it would be easy to show that $u \pm c \in W^{1,2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B\subset \Omega$ be a (non-empty) ball. Then the restriction of $u$ to $B$ is in $W^{1,2}(B)$, and $\min(u,c) \in W^{1,2}(B)$ (since the constant function $c$ on $B$ is in $W^{1,2}(B)$). This proves $u\in W^{1,2}_{loc}(\Omega)$.

The weak derivative of $\min(u,c)$ on $B$ is either zero or equal to that of $u$, so $|D\min(u,c)|\le |Du|$ on $B$, and hence on $\Omega$. This proves $D\min(u,c) \in L^2(\Omega)$.

Since $u\in L^2(D)$, it follows that the set $\Omega_c:=\{x: \ u(x)>c\}$ has finite measure. Then
$$
\int_\Omega (\min(u,c))^2 = \int_{\Omega_c} (\min(u,c))^2+\int_{\Omega\setminus \Omega_c} (\min(u,c))^2 = c^2 |\Omega_c| + \int_{\Omega\setminus \Omega_c} u^2 < +\infty.
$$
This proves $\min(u,c)\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! May I ask why the weak derivative of $min(u,c)$ exists? I can see why it exists locally, but how can we extend it to exist on all of $\Omega$?

Comment: Here is a different viewpoint: In the question you gave the 'intuitive' formula for the weak derivative. To verify that it is indeed the (global) weak derivative, we have to test with smooth functions with compact support. This support can be covered by finitely many balls. And we are back to the local situation.